# Parse date into dd-MMM-yy

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

Friends...

IN my ms access database i store date format dd-MMM-yy.
and in search query pass dates as parameter.
but my system cantain date format mm/dd/yyyy 
so,how can i convert this format in dd-MMM-yy before pass this date to query
now,i m using folling code..but give error....String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate.ToString(), "dd-MMM-yy", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//startdate is datepicker
```

query...

```
s = new OleDbDataAdapter("
      SELECT opd_patient_master.*, patient_operation.* 
      FROM opd_patient_master, patient_operation 
      WHERE opd_patient_master.pid= patient_operation.pid 
         and opd_patient_master.rdid= patient_operation.rdid 
         and odate >= #" + startdate + "# and odate<=# " + enddate + "# 
         and operation= '" + oprtype + "'", mycon);
```

Comment: and `enddate` is also a `DateTimePicker`?

Answer (score 2):

Use parameters, you don't need to convert to strings

```
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT opd_patient_master.*, patient_operation.* FROM   opd_patient_master, patient_operation where opd_patient_master.pid= patient_operation.pid and   opd_patient_master.rdid= patient_operation.rdid and odate >= ?  and odate<= ? and operation= ?", mycon))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", startDateTimePicker.Value); // use DateTime input here as startdate
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", endDateTimePicker.Value); // use DateTime input here as enddate
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oprtype", oprtype);
    using (OleDbDataAdapter s = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
       // do something with adapter 
    }

}
```

Note that you can get the selected `DateTime` value from Date Time picker control directly. using `DateTimePicker.Value` property

Comment: It looks like that the `OP` doesn't know how to extract the DateTime value from DateTimePicker, you should include a notice about that (He used `DateTimePicker.ToString()` to get its DateTime value.

Comment: It might be worth adding that `startdate.ToString()` returns the string representation of the DTP control, just for clarification, but maybe it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using [parameter queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) is much the better option, then these formatting issues will be taken care of.

For the current approach, a solution is to use the standard ISO date-format YYYY-MM-DD, passing the date as a string:

```
string sStartDate = startdate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

".. and odate >= #" + sStartDate + "#..
```

[Custom Date and Time Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) :MSDN